# Sorting by power

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, sorting

I want to sort this table by column "d" such that Mathematica should also take the exponential values into account. Can somebody help me here?

[image: Table]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please edit your question and include all relevant information, including your table and any Mathematica code you are using.

Comment: The input is: Partition[Flatten[fitteddata], Length[fitteddata[[1]]]] // TableForm     and I want to keep the first row.

Comment: No, it's not possible as it's an output of many input files. I just want to know if there is a trick to sorting such Flatten table.

Comment: @Miss, evaluate ``Partition[Flatten[fitteddata], Length[fitteddata[[1]]]]`` (without `TableForm`!) , and paste the ouput in your question.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You can learn to ask better questions by visiting the site's Help page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> it's not possible as it's an output of many input files

This makes it little harder, but here is an example.

The idea is to use `SortBy[data, #[[5]] &]`  this sorts the whole data using 5th column as *key* . Make sure not to use `TableForm` when sorting as it is a wrapper. Do the `SortBy` on the row data before adding the tittle row and before adding `TableForm` to it.

```
title = {"phiA(deg)", "z0", "w", "l", "d", "dnm", "ξ", "ζ"}
data = {{33, 50, 0.00008, 0.01, 1.0*10^(-8), 4.8*10^(-9), 1, 1},
  {24.3, 50, 0.00008, 0.01, 1.1*10^(-8), 4.8*10^(-9), 1, 1},
  {38, 50, 0.00008, 0.01, 1.2*10^(-8), 4.8*10^(-9), 1, 1},
  {30, 50, 0.00008, 0.01, 1.3*10^(-8), 4.8*10^(-9), 1, 1},
  {22, 50, 0.00008, 0.01, 0.9*10^(-8), 4.8*10^(-9), 1, 1},
  {35, 50, 0.00008, 0.01, 0.8*10^(-8), 4.8*10^(-9), 1, 1},
  {30, 50, 0.00008, 0.01, 1.5*10^(-8), 4.8*10^(-9), 1, 1}
  }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now sort the data (without the title row) then add the title row next

```
dataSorted = SortBy[data, #[[5]] &] (*sort on 5th column*)
({title}~Join~dataSorted) // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]